# Elbow Arrow between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Would like to draw an arrow between node (a) and node (b) similar to hand drawn in the attached image named document3. Following is the code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,shapes,arrows,backgrounds,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    background rectangle/.style={% Background style
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners,          
        },
    show background rectangle,        
    >=latex,
    line width=1pt
]

\node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG1) at (0,-1){\includegraphics[scale=1]{document_1.pdf}};
\draw (FIG1)++(0,-3.6) node[scale=1]{(a)};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG2) at (6,-1.9){\includegraphics[scale=1]{document_2.pdf}};
\draw (FIG2)++(1.8,-2.2) node[scale=1]{(b)};
 \draw (FIG2)++(1.2,3.2) node[scale=1]{Failure Correlation Identification};   
\node[ draw, red, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(FIG1)(FIG2)](node1){};     
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG4) at (-2,-8.2) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{Distance_Matrix_3.pdf}};
 \draw (FIG4)++(.3,-2.05) node[scale=1]{(c)};
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG5) at (2.7,-8.4) {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{S1_C1.pdf}};     
 \draw (FIG5)++(.2,-1.85) node[scale=1]{(d)};    
 \node[ draw, green, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(FIG4)(FIG5), minimum width=2cm, minimum height = 4.6cm](node2){};     
 \draw (FIG4)++(2.5,1.9) node[scale=1]{Hierarchical Clustering};   
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG6) at (8,-8.3) {\includegraphics[scale=.27]{Kmeans.pdf}};  
 \node[ draw, blue, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(FIG6), minimum width=4cm, minimum height = 4.6cm] at (8,-8.2)(node3){};
 \draw (FIG6)++(.1,-1.95) node[scale=1]{(e)};
 \draw (FIG4)++(10,1.9) node[scale=1]{Non-Hierarchical Clustering};   
\draw [-latex, thick] (FIG4) -- (FIG4 -| FIG5.west);
\draw[->] (node1.south) |- ($(node1.south) - (0,5mm)$) -| (node2.north);
\draw[->] (node1.south) |- ($(node1.south) - (0,5mm)$) -| (node3.north);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: document3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have the graphics files you are including but you may try

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    background rectangle/.style={% Background style
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners,          
        },
    show background rectangle,        
    >=latex,
    line width=1pt
]

\node[inner sep=0pt,yscale=2] (FIG1) at (0,-1){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}};
\draw (FIG1)++(0,-3.6) node[scale=1]{(a)};
\node[inner sep=0pt,xscale=3] (FIG2) at (6,-1.9){\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}};
\draw (FIG2)++(1.8,-2.2) node[scale=1]{(b)};
\draw[thick,-latex] (FIG1.20) -| (FIG2)
node[midway,above]{Failure Correlation Identification} ;
\node[ draw, red, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(FIG1)(FIG2)](node1){};     
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG4) at (-2,-8.2) {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-c}};
 \draw (FIG4)++(.3,-2.05) node[scale=1]{(c)};
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG5) at (2.7,-8.4)
 {\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image-duck}};     
 \draw (FIG5)++(.2,-1.85) node[scale=1]{(d)};    
 \node[ draw, green, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(FIG4)(FIG5), minimum width=2cm, minimum height = 4.6cm](node2){};     
 \draw (FIG4)++(2.5,1.9) node[scale=1]{Hierarchical Clustering};   
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (FIG6) at (8,-8.3) {\includegraphics[scale=.27]{example-image-duck}};  
 \node[ draw, blue, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(FIG6), minimum width=4cm, minimum height = 4.6cm] at (8,-8.2)(node3){};
 \draw (FIG6)++(.1,-1.95) node[scale=1]{(e)};
 \draw (FIG4)++(10,1.9) node[scale=1]{Non-Hierarchical Clustering};   
\draw [-latex, thick] (FIG4) -- (FIG4 -| FIG5.west);
\draw[->] (node1.south) |- ($(node1.south) - (0,5mm)$) -| (node2.north);
\draw[->] (node1.south) |- ($(node1.south) - (0,5mm)$) -| (node3.north);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't want an angle in the arrow.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Do you just want to have two straight lines meeting at a 90 degree angle?

Comment: Yes and the line meeting with image (b) must have an arrow at the end.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I updated.